# unable to call backend service without using API Gateway Proxy Integration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a PATCH method/resource in my API Gateway that needs to call backend service when I select to use proxy integration I was able to get the proper response but If I disable proxy integration I'm getting a 406 error from backend with `PATCH /error` Below are my API settings
[image]
[image]

Do I need to add any extra configuration under the mapping template?

Comment: Why did you disable proxy integration if it was working?

Comment: @Marcin If I use proxy that might create CORS issue in future, so wanted to disable proxy

Comment: Without proxy, you have to use [custom integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html). Have you set it up properly?

Comment: @Marcin I'm bit new API Gateway, what do you mean by setting up custom integration properly, I'm able to see requests are hitting the backend service but the issue is I think the body and URL are not transformed in the right way. That's where I'm having diffculties to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

@patrick I'm not sure if this will help, but this might give you some insight as to the actual error message.  In APIGW Console, select the "Gateway Responses" item on the left-hand menu.  Find Default 4XX and add a Response Template of `application/json`.  Set the Response Template Body to `{"message":$context.error.messageString}`.  This should deliver a more specific error message as to what is wrong.